# Jupyter Notebook not ploting output using plotly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, plotly

I am working on choropleth using plotly in Jupyter Notebook.I want to plot choropleth but its showing me empty output.I am working with offline plotly.In html its genrated chart successfuly but when i tried offline it shows me empty output.please tell me how i solve this error.
here is my code

> ```
> from plotly.graph_objs import *
> from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
> from plotly.offline.offline import _plot_html
> init_notebook_mode(connected=True) 
> for col in state_df.columns:
>     state_df[col] = state_df[col].astype(str)
> scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
>             [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]
>
> state_df['text'] = state_df['StateCode'] + '<br>' +'TotalPlans '+state_df['TotalPlans']
> data = [ dict(
>         type='choropleth',
>         colorscale = scl,
>         autocolorscale = False,
>         locations = state_df['StateCode'],
>         z = state_df['TotalPlans'].astype(float),
>         locationmode = 'USA-states',
>         text = state_df['text'],
>         marker = dict(
>             line = dict (
>                 color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
>                 width = 2
>             )
>         ),
>         colorbar = dict(
>             title = "Millions USD"
>         )
>     ) ]
> layout = dict(
>         title = 'Plan by States',
>         geo = dict(
>             scope='usa',
>             projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
>             showlakes = True,
>             lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
>         ),
>     )
>
> fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
> plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `dict`ionary to `iplot` which in contradiction to the documentation can handle only `Figure` objects and not dictionaries.

Try

```
fig = Figure(data=[data], layout=layout)
```

and it should work.